# Guardar el valor de un input en una variable en c#

Tags: c#, input

Hola quiero guardar el valor de un input de tipo text en una variable y después mostrar el valor, esto es lo que tengo:
*mi formulario con los campos que necesito mostrar el momento de dar clic en guardar

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Formulario.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="TicketJSON.Formulario" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>Solicitud de ticket</h2>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Nombre:</asp:Label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="boxname"/>
        <br />
        
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label">Clasificación:</asp:Label>
        <select name="classification">
            <option value="Cambio/Devolución/Reembolso">Cambio/Devolución/Reembolso</option>
            <option value="Duda/Queja">Duda/Queja</option>
            <option value="Facturación">Facturación</option>
        </select>
         <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Al momento de dar clic quiero que me muestre los valores de los inputs, pero me marca error, me dice que boxname y MessageBox no existen en el contexto actual.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace TicketJSON
{
public partial class Formulario : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String nombre = boxname.Text;
        MessageBox.Show('hola' + nombre);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Saludos. A cada componente que quieras tener acceso en el código (en tu caso) C# debes agregarle `runat="server"` de lo contrario no lo reconoce; lo de `MessageBox.Show();` en ambientre web no te lo reconocera (si tu intención es generar como un **alert**); ahora que si es un proceso que genera código para mostrar mensaje del lado del cliente te hace falta agregar la libreria que para ello corresponda.

Comment: Hola @RobertoLeOr ya le agregué el `runat="server"`, pero al momento de poner  String nombre = boxname.Text; en el Text me marca el siguiente error **CS1061 C# does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Para los elementos `<input />` en vez de `Text` es `value` (no recuerdo si es **V** mayúsculas y minúsculas. Si usas el `<asp:TextBox>` es con ello el `Text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personalmente no sé cómo se manejan los imputs en el Code Behind, pero lo que podes hacer es cambiarlo por un `<asp:TextBox/>` de manera que tu `.aspx` quedaría algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>Solicitud de ticket</h2>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Nombre:</asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <!-- solo cambia esta linea -->
        <br />
    
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label">Clasificación:</asp:Label>
        <select name="classification">
            <option value="Cambio/Devolución/Reembolso">Cambio/Devolución/Reembolso</option>
            <option value="Duda/Queja">Duda/Queja</option>
            <option value="Facturación">Facturación</option>
        </select>
         <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Y luego en tu clase `.cs` (o como te dije antes, el Code Behind) dentro del metodo `Button1_Click` guardas en la variable el texto del `TextBox` buscandolo por su id:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nombre = name.Text;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + "hola" + nombre + "');", true);
}
```

El `MessageBox` como tal no existe en en asp.net, lo que tenés que hacer es mandarle una alerta al cliente (el navegador) que podes hacerlo de la manera que te puse en la segunda linea del método `Button1_Click`. Sé que no es muy agradable a la vista, pero es lo que te ofrece asp.net.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Hola @Matias me funcionó lo que me comentas, un detalle más, me podrías orientar en cómo hacerlo para la opción de clasificación es que ahí es una lista, para guardar el valor del value en una variable, gracias.

Comment: Cambiá el `<select/>` por un `<asp:DropDownList/>` y completalo asi:

<asp:DropDownList ID="classification" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Cambio/Devolución/Reembolso"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Duda/Queja"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Facturación"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

En el `.cs` para guardarlo en una variable es:

string seleccion = classification.SelectedValue;

Yo le puse números al value porque a mí me gusta poner números, pero le podes poner una cadena si querés

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias @Matias

Comment: De nada. Me alegra haberte ayudado!

Answer (score -1):

Buen dia, se que es tarde para dar una respuesta, estoy también recién aprendiendo. Y me he encontrado con una buena solución usando: BeginForm, les dejo el enlace para los futuros aprendices

```
//html <p> @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customers", FormMethod.Get)) { @Html.TextBox("campo2") @Html.TextBox("nameToSearch") <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> } </p> //controlador public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> Index(string? nameToSearch, string? campo2) {
```

https://si.ua.es/es/documentacion/asp-net-mvc-3/3-dia/buscador.html

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/332370)

Comment: //html
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customers", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("campo2")        
        @Html.TextBox("nameToSearch")
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    }
</p>
//controlador
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> Index(string? nameToSearch, string? campo2)
        {
-----

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios. Además, no olvides explicar brevemente tanto el contenido del enlace como el código: lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.